# Accessing the HTML contents of WP7 WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

Once I've navigated to a URL, can I retrieve the HTML that's inside the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402601%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) control?

Maybe there are some javascript hacks I can do via [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.invokescript%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and [ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - use this function:

`WebBrowser.SaveToString()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.savetostring(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: nice one.  how did i miss that?